# UIButton's UIControlStateHighlighted only working for longer taps

Tags: ios7

I set titleColor and backgroundImage for my UIButton, which works if I press the UIButton a little bit longer. But for very quick taps, the change isn't visible. Is there a possibility to at least let it flickr for these kinds of taps?

```
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [button setBackgroundImage:whiteBackgroundImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setBackgroundImage:redBackgroundImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [button setBackgroundImage:redBackgroundImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Comment: This is a very good question! I am facing this problem for a long time and can't seem to find a solution. Have you found a workaround?

Comment: Thank you for this question, I was facing the same problem. You should consider accepting the answer as correct if it helped you.

Answer (score 2):

this is due to you adding a button to a UITableView or UIScrollVIew.

For buttons in UITableView add this to your ViewDidLoad:

```
self.tableView.delaysContentTouches = NO;
for (id obj in self.tableView.subviews)
{
    if ([obj respondsToSelector:@selector(setDelaysContentTouches:)])
    {
        [obj setDelaysContentTouches:NO];
    }
}
```

For buttons in UIScrollView add this:

```
self.scrollView.delaysContentTouches = NO;
```

Comment: You are a life saver!

Comment: Thank you kind sir, this worked!

Note: this also works on collectionView and simple "self.collectionView.delaysContentTouches = NO" was enough for me.